# How to make option to run one directory or all directory in shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to make the decision for Shell script. Either to run only one directory or all directory. This is my coding:

```
#!/bin/sh

function_run ()
{
python Declare.py
for a in $1
do
 echo $a

   # Loop to call the file.
   for i in 1 2 3 4 5
   do
       # Cut the row and column
       grep -v '^#' $a/result*.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cat > pos.txt
   done


python Calculate.py $a/pos.txt $a/neg.txt $a/pos$i.txt $a/neg$i.txt
python Graph.py $a/output*.py $a/output1.py
python allMax.py "$a" $a/output1.py $a/maxList.py
done
python allMaxGraph.py maxList.py maxTPRlist.py max1TPRlist.py
}

echo "Which KO you want to run?(If all just put ALL): "
read input
a=K*
if [ $input = 'ALL' ]
then
   function_run $a
elif [ -d  $input ]
then
   function_run $input
else
   echo "File $input does not exist"
fi
```

But when I want to run for all directory and I input **ALL**. But only one directory work and the script stop. It not run for all directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are reusing the variable name `a` inside the function_run(). Change the local variable name or use `local a`.
You have more problems.
Start using quotes around variables, such as

```
a="K*"
if [ "$input" = "ALL" ]
```

You have a check for an existing dir. That check is skipped when you use ALL. Move the check to the function.
I do not understand your function. You are looping with $i, but never use the different values.
Your function is parsing the input with `for a in $1`. Use `$*` for all parameters.
When you think you are finished, also test with a directory name with a space inside (`mkdir "Know what"`).